# (Windows 10) How to make the firewall reload the config from registry?

Tags: windows-10, windows-firewall

After changing some firewall rules in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules` they show up in the `wf.msc` under "Inboud Rules", but in "Monitoring / Firewall" they are not present and a connection test confirms that they are not active.

Stopping and restarting the `MpsSvc` service solved this in previous versions of Windows, but in Windows 10 it can not be stopped.

Also this does not help (the changed settings are still not activated after running them):

```
netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off
netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state on
```

So, how to make the firewall apply such changes?

Comment: Why not change the rules using a more supported method. For instance, whatever your need is to change the registry should be accomplished just as easily by using `netsh advfirewall` like you already referenced.

Comment: @Appleoddity Well, I have this situation I need to solve. Is there a way to "recreate" the settings from the registry using those commands?

Comment: Yes, of course. https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-8/top-10-windows-firewall-netsh-commands

Comment: In particular look at the bottom for the one labeled **1. Export and import firewall settings:** per the link @Appleoddity provided... I think at least... lol